# Can't link ncurses with Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, c++11

I included  `<ncurses.h>` , but can't link ncurses's libs in .pro file. I'm trying like this:

> LIBS += -L"/usr/lib/" -libncurses.a

I tried different variations of linking (with/without file_type, different variations of directory), but it didn't help. Then I decided to link via console using:

```
g++ -lncurses main.cpp snake.cpp
```

Tried to put `-lncurses` in different places of command.

It gives me an error:

```
undefined reference to move(); (ncurses's func)
```

And it doesn't want to compile C++11 features, like `std::list.empalce_front();`. The reason I'm asking for help for second problem in the same question, is that if would able compile only via console, so i won't be able to use C++11 features, but i want to!

P.S. Of course, the main problem is with linking ncurses's libs

Answer (score 1):

http://www.lucidarme.me/?p=3961 Here You can find a solution. Main reason is You incorrectly set project:

```
LIBS += -lncurses
```

Check a link I sent You. Everything is there clear.